# Is it possible to get git to ignore a corrupt blob

Tags: git

I have a corrupt blob object which can be seen here

```
> git fsck --full
error: unable to unpack 5426a4097ea6a3597a1674b0b7fa67f395006f2a header
error: inflateEnd: stream consistency error (no message)
fatal: loose object 5426a4097ea6a3597a1674b0b7fa67f395006f2a (stored in .git/obj
ects/54/26a4097ea6a3597a1674b0b7fa67f395006f2a) is corrupt
```

git cat-file -t 542... also errors with the same unable to unpack header

I've checked other machines, and all have the corrupt version.

I worked through this process - 
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt and narrowed it down to a particular file (Site.css) and a date range (Commits before and after) but I'm not going to be able to reconstruct the changes to recover the file, as it was a part of a fairly major set of changes made a long time ago: So long ago that I really don't care about that bit of history.

As I now have the hashes of the commits before and after, can I do something to just forget about that bit of the history - kind of a rebase (although I imagine a rebase would fail - not tried it yet!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`git-replace` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace). The replacement mechanism allows you to drop in a new blob with a different hash as a substitute for an old one. This may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do. There may be more elegant solutions, but for something that'll get you where you need to be, this'll do the trick.

What you'll need:

- The SHA1 of the commit immediately before the one that introduced the duff blob, `<LastGoodCommit>`.
- The SHA1 of the commit that contains the duff blob, `<BadCommit>`.

What you need to do:

1. Get a list of all the branches and tags that contain the duff commit, and save these off:

   ```
   git branch --contains <BadCommit> >branches.txt
   git tag --contains <BadCommit> >tags.txt
   ```
2. Check out the good commit:

   ```
   git checkout <LastGoodCommit>
   ```
3. Create a new commit that will replace the commit containing the bad blob.

   You may be able to use `git cherry-pick -n <BadCommit>` to get the changes, or possibly not. I can't test it, so you'll need to try yourself and see what happens. If it doesn't work, you should be able to checkout individual files and directories using `git checkout <BadCommit>:<path>`.

   You'll need to work out what you want that `site.css` file to look like in this commit. I can see two options:

   - Just leave it as it was in `<LastGoodCommit>`
   - Find the next time you have a good blob for `site.css` in one of your branches (ideal situation: it's the same in all branches) and use that.

   Whichever you do, note the new commit hash `<NewGoodCommit>`.
4. Rebase all your branches, listed in `branches.txt` from above, that contained the bad commit onto this new commit. Depending on which option you picked at step 3, you may have merge conflicts; just resolve these using the new version of the file.

   If all the branches have the same following version of `site.css`, you should be able to be confident there will be no clashes, and use the following one-liner to do all the rebases:

   ```
   while read branchname; do git rebase --onto <NewGoodCommit> <BadCommit> "$branchname" || echo "Failed rebasing $branchname" && break; done
   ```
5. Go through your tags (in `tags.txt`) and create replacements for each one on the newly rebased branches. Sadly I don't know a way to automate this.